# Visibility is Collapsed after set to Hidden

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Using AvalonDock 2, I have default implementation to change visibility from ViewModel:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xcad:LayoutAnchorableItem}">
     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Model.IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static Visibility.Hidden}}" />
```

When set this `IsVisible` to false (or call LayoutAnchorable.Hide() directly)
something strange happens in method `LayoutAnchorableItem._anchorable_IsVisibleChanged`. After this line

```
Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

something in ExternalCode makes `Visibility` Collapsed. No breakpoint triggers in `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`, but if I remove `<Setter Property="Visibility"`, all goes fine, `Visibility == Visibility.Hidden`.

Where may problem be?

Comment: In a docking framework, making elements collapsed when they are invisible seems reasonable. Why would you want something to be invisible instead of collapsed when you want things to dock to each other?

Comment: Avalon works such way. I wonder, where setting property intercepts.